# Posting a tweet in twitter using python selenium for a poc

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to post a tweet in Twitter using python and selenium
But at the time of posting it is giving me timeout error.

I have the code ready....

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
# create a new Chrome session
chromedriver = "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
chromedriver = "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
 #driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.implicitly_wait(30)
 driver.maximize_window()

 # navigate to the application home page
 driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")


 # get the username textbox
 login_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-username-field")
 login_field.clear()

  # enter username
  login_field.send_keys("")
   time.sleep(1)

  #get the password textbox
   password_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-password- 
    field")
    password_field.clear()

    #enter password
       time.sleep(10)
       password_field.send_keys("")
       time.sleep(10)
       password_field.submit()

       autotw1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 140).until(
      EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id='tweet-box-home- 
      timeline']")))
       autotw1.send_keys("""Just a testing """)  

       tweet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='add-tweet-button 
       ']//following-sibling::button[contains(@class,'tweet-action')]")
       tweet.click()
```

I am getting the below error.

---

TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     39 
     40 autotw1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 140).until(
---> 41 EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id='tweet-box-home-timeline']")))

Comment: What are you observing when the script is being executed? Do you manage to pass authentication successfully?

Comment: I am able to log in successfully. But at the time of tweeting, I am getting the error...timeout...

Comment: Attach a screenshot of the filed u r trying to click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this locator:`By.CLASS_NAME, 'DraftEditor-root'`.

You must click on the element to bring up other elements to write the tweet, which is:`By.CLASS_NAME, 'public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-root')`, and use `ActionChains` to send text.

First, following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

After submit login please try below:

```
password_field.submit()

autotw1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'DraftEditor-root')))
autotw1.click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-root')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).send_keys("""Just a testing """).perform()

sendTw = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@role="button"]/div/span/span')))
sendTw.click()
```

Comment: @frianH.It works. Please send screenshots...I want to understand how to find the ist element and next..

Answer (score 1):

You have provided incorrect xpath and css value in your script. Kindly run below scrip with your own credentials and don't forget to update chrome driver path.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


# Open Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome('Path to chrome driver')
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")

# get the username textbox
login_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-username-field")
login_field.clear()

# enter username
login_field.send_keys("")
time.sleep(1)

# get the password textbox
password_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-password-field")
password_field.clear()

# enter password

password_field.send_keys("")

password_field.submit()

autotw1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n r-xoduu5 r-1sp51qo r-mk0yit r-13qz1uu']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(autotw1).click(autotw1).send_keys("Just a testing").perform()


tweet = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0']//span[@class='css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0'][contains(text(),'Tweet')]")))
tweet.click()
```

Comment: @vinod mehta: please check above solution

Comment: @ Rock it is working.But  the final tweet is not being posted...I am not able to understand the inner working about the code.Please help regarding that....

Comment: I have already verified this solution y'day and it was working on local. May be issue with n/w so added wait. Please check it and would you be kind enough to accept this answer and hit upvote button

Comment: Would you be kind enough to accept my answer if your problem is resolved